# number format on Zend Currency

Tags: zend-framework, zend-currency

I am developing a site Zend based but I have the followin problem:

```
$currency = new Zend_Currency();
$currency->toCurrency(20, array('currency' => 'EUR','number_format' => '#0.#'));
```

Gives me `20,00 EUR` but I need `20.00 EUR` (that is why i set number_format), Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `number_format` to just [format](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.currency.options.html).

> Excerpt from Zend_Currency Docs in reference to the *options array('format' =>'#0.00')*:
>  **format**: Defines the format which
>   should be used for displaying numbers. This number-format includes for
>   example the thousand separator. You can either use a default format by
>   giving a locale identifier, or define the number-format manually. If
>   no format is set the locale from the Zend_Currency object will be
>   used.